# In a graph with a downward trend, if the decrease stops is this still referred to as a plateau?

Tags: data-visualization, terminology

I know that when an upward trend slows/stops growing we call it a plateau, but I can't separate that from the imagery of a geological plateau.

Does plateau apply to the second scenario with negative growth below?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say so...plateau does, however, seems to imply relatively high flat territory.  One might call this a 'bottom' or 'floor'.